# optimal bid strategy for uniform distribution

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, auction-theory

Ten players take part in the following auction for a $\$$100 project from some company. If some player $i$ wins, the company will pay him his bid $b_i$. The ten players submit bids simultaneously, and the highest score wins the prize.The bids are given by
\begin{align}
b_i=100(1+x_i)
\end{align}
where $x_i\in (0,0.2)$.  The score of each player can be calculated in the following rules. Firstly, calculate the average value of
\begin{align}
\bar{x}=\frac{1}{10}(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10})
\end{align}
Secondly, the bids that deviate $1/4$ of the average value will be eliminated,
\begin{align}
\frac{|x_j-\bar{x}|}{\bar{x}}\geq \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
Thirdly, we calculate the average value of the remained bids,
\begin{align}
\bar{x'}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a=1}^mx_a
\end{align}
Finally, the final score is determined by the following,
\begin{align}
S=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&100-50\frac{|x_j-\bar{x'}|}{\bar{x'}},\,\,\,\,\,\, x_j<\bar{x'}\\
&100-100\frac{|x_j-\bar{x'}|}{\bar{x'}},\,\,\,\,\,\, x_j>\bar{x'}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
W want to know the optimal bid. Is this the standard question in Nash's theory? I am not familiar with Nash's theory.

Comment: It looks at the start that the bids are between $100$ and $118$ (so why bid if the prize is only $100$?)

Comment: Possible remedy to the comment of @Henry.  Edit your posting to have the prize worth $120$.

Comment: @user2661923，you mean this?

Comment: If the prize is worth 120 rather than 100, then it makes sense that someone submitting bids between 100 thru 120, exclusive, would hope to win the auction.  That is all that I am saying.

Comment: Sorry, I think I make some mistake in the problem. Now I think I have fixed it.